# Is there anyone to solve cross browser problem?

Tags: iphone, cross-browser, responsive

I have faced some problem with cross browser,in the picture below you can see,in every phone and browser the arrows looking perfect but an iPhone it's not looking perfect,if someone can know what is margin-right and margin-left that can only work for iphone not for others,

iPhone View
[in iPhone looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IypCx.jpg)

All browsers view
[in every browser looking perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PedXB.jpg)

I'm trying to solve the problem,that as there any solution that margin-left and right only work for iPhone